# How to return a list of sceduled background tasks in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background, android-workmanager

I've been using the *Workmanager* plugin for flutter and would like to return a list of currently registered background tasks using something analogous to `print(Workmanager.registeredBackgroundTasks)`.

This isn't a command within Workmanager. Is there a way to do this? presumably it's different for iOS and Android.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: @pfmaggi https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager, the plugin doesn't have a command for this but I know that it schedules tasks so logically there should be a way to view scheduled tasks